# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in MCMV code

Tags: matlab

The below code gives me a error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> lookmcvmt at 18

```
M(:,:,j,i) = mcmvOUT2((k+1):(k+Nz), i:Nt:Nr);
```

Please help to solve.

```
load MCMVout1xzy
mcmvOUT2 = MCMVout1xzy;
whos
[Nr2 Nr] = size(mcmvOUT2);
Ny = 51;
Nx = 51;
Nz = 41;
Nt = 10;
M = zeros(Nz,Nx,Ny,Nt);
for j=1:Ny
    for i=1:Nt
        k = Nz*(j-1);
        M(:,:,j,i) = mcmvOUT2((k+1):(k+Nz), i:Nt:Nr);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error 'subscripted assignment dimension mismatch' means you are trying to assign a block of values into a space that is the wrong size.

This entity

```
mcmvOUT2((k+1):(k+Nz), i:Nt:Nr);
```

represents a matrix of values in 2 dimensions. Its size is defined by the two ranges specified by `(k+1):(k+Nz)` and `i:Nt:Nr` - you can check its size by typing

```
size(mcmvOUT2((k+1):(k+Nz), i:Nt:Nr))
```

The space you are trying to fit it into has to be exactly the same dimensions. The size of the range specified by

```
M(:,:,j,i)
```

is defined by the `Nz` and `Nx` arguments to the `zeros` call with which you preallocated the array.

We can't test this because the `MCMVout1xzy` file containing your data is not given, but you will be able to solve this yourself by using the `size` command and making sure all your dimensions match.

Because matlab uses column-wise indexing, and a lot of us are used to the row-wise paradigm of cartesian coordinate systems, getting the order of your indexes right can be confusing - this is the root of a lot of these kinds of error (for me anyway).

Things to check: your dimensions `Nz` etc. are correct and the order of your `Nz` etc. variables in the `zeros` call is correct.

Comment: This is what i got.. will this data help?

Name                Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  MCMVout1xzy      2091x51            853128  double              
  mcmvOUT2         2091x51            853128  double              

K>> size(mcmvOUT2((k+1):(k+Nz), i:Nt:Nr))

ans =     41     6

Comment: What you want to do is compare the size of the RHS with the size of the LHS and make sure they have the same values in the same order. If they don't then you can look at the ones that are different and use that information to work out how to alter your code so that they are.